# Why hasn't 14.04 (64-bit) claimed my Intel PRO/100 VE ethernet connection?

Tags: networking, drivers, intel

I've installed 14.04 on my old Sony Vaio VGN-FE41E and the Ethernet connection does not work.

`sudo lshw`

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Ethernet controller
product: PRO/100 VE Network Connection
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 8
bus info: pci@0000:0a:08.0
version: 02
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm cap_list
configuration: latency=64 maxlatency=56 mingnt=8
resources: memory:d2005000-d2005fff ioport:6000(size=64)
```

`sudo lsmod` shows nothing (completely empty except for headers, 'Modules, Size, Used By').

Note: This is not the only piece of hardware listed as `UNCLAIMED` by `lshw`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I manged to fix this problem myself by recreating the bootable USB stick with a different tool and reinstalling from scratch. I did try two installations from the previous bootable USB stick with same results.

As I used the same verified ISO I can only assume that it was the tool I used to create the bootable USB stick (although I don't understand how/why). I won't name/blame the tool I used though. I think it was probably down to using an old version and/or choosing the wrong options when creating it.

Moral of the story: Use a simple and up to date tool for creating bootable USB stick. Probably best to go the one most recommended in your distributions doc! What worked for me was Ubuntu 'Startup Disk Creator'.